# Status 0xC0000121 - Delete File

Tags: c, driver, delete-file

Good day,

i have a big problem, i want to delete a file stored in "System32\drivers" but everything i tried didn't work except normal file deletion (rightclick delete..).

Here is my Code:

```
    NTSTATUS DeleteImage(
    VOID
)
{
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    UNICODE_STRING uPath = { 0 };
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES obAttr = { 0 };
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK statusBlock = { 0 };

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uPath, L"\\SystemRoot\\System32\\drivers\\**.sys");
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&obAttr, &uPath, OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);

    // Get file handle
    status = ZwCreateFile(&hFile,
        (READ_CONTROL | DELETE | SYNCHRONIZE),
        &obAttr,
        &statusBlock,
        NULL,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        (FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE),
        FILE_OPEN,
        (FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE | FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT | FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE),
        NULL,
        0);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        return status;

    status = ZwClose(hFile);  //<< Status 0xC0000121

    return status;
}
```

And here is the DBGPrint: "DriverEntry: Cant delete file. Abort  -  Status: 0xC0000121"

I also tried it with "ZwOpenFile" and "ZwDeleteFile" but nothing works, hopefully someone can help me out and explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: Possibly your driver does not have enough permissions to the file or the file has been opened in exclusive mode.

Comment: Found the solution, i was loading the file with LdrLoadDll and forgot to unload it >.<

Answer (score 0):

**0xC0000121 = STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE**
An attempt has been made to remove a file or directory that cannot be deleted.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx